# How do I get Node.js on Azure to start up with ES6 module syntax, it fails now though it works at home?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, es6-modules

I've been publishing a NodeJs Express web app on Azure as an experiment.  It was working great when I used ES6 / ESM syntax only in the JS that the browser used.

Since I prefer ES6 syntax, I reworked my server-end JS to use ES6 classes and ESM import syntax, including changes to the package.json (type = module) and to the Express-provided files.

All of that works great when I run it locally (WebStorm on a Mac).  I am running NodeJs 12.18.2.

When I publish the app to Azure, though, it chokes.  I get a blank page when I go to the URL.  It turns out that the app doesn't start and so no page.

The error message suggests that only on Azure, NodeJs just doesn't get the whole module idea:

```
import express from "express";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Again, I only see this on Azure.  Azure is running NodeJs 12.13.0.  I'm using Kudu as the build process.

On my machine it runs beautifully, because I have the root `package.json` file set up correctly (it seems):

```
{
  "name": "--redacted--",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

But the `package.json` file is identical on Azure, though, and it doesn't prevent the fail.

Here's the beginning of the code that's failing at the top of `app.js`, although the error is generic to *any* use of `import`:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  Syntax looks right and works at home, but fails on Azure.  Is it a config / dependency / NodeJs version issue?

I've already tried things like using the esm package or not using it (I don't need it locally), changing the start script in package.json to include `-r esm` or to exclude it (it isn't needed in my local runs), and to use the deprecated `--experimental-modules`, and so on.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work on Azure even though it does locally?  Please help me out!

Comment: @user3777460 Did you get this resolved. I am running into the exact same issue. My node.js v18 app works perfectly on my local and but fails on Azure app service with module error.